# window.showModalDialog resizable property not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing a page in asp.net, and I have this script that opens a modal window. It works perfectly, but the resizable property seems to not be working as I can resize the window once it is opened.

```
Dim script as String = "window.showModalDialog('" + page + "','','unadorned:yes; dialogWidth:330px; dialogHeight:210px; center:yes ; resizable:no; scrollbars:no; toolbar:no; copyhistory:no; menubar:no; status:no ; addressbar:no');"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "alertaerror", script, True)
```

I need help with that property, is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers simply doesn't let you open a window that is not possible to resize, so the `resizable` setting has no effect in those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Guffa says. However, if you are really set having the dialog not re-sizable, you can use a jQuery library like [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or other javascript to create the affect of a modal dialog.